# Apache camel: SFTP: files downloaded multiple times

Tags: apache-camel

I've defined the following camel route:

```
    RouteBuilder rb = new RouteBuilder() {
        @Override
        public void configure() throws Exception {
            from("sftp://myhost//path/to/files/")
            .to("log:loggingCategory?level=INFO")
            .to("file:///tmp/");
        }
    };
```

When I start the context with this route camel does connect and it downloads the files. My problem is that camel repeats downloading the same files until the context is shut down. Why does the FTP2 component do this and how can I stop it?

I've included version 2.10.4 of camel-core and camel-ftp via maven.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [Indempotent Consumer](http://camel.apache.org/idempotent-consumer.html) does the trick. Docs of [the FTP2 component](http://camel.apache.org/ftp2.html) refer to [the File2 component](http://camel.apache.org/file2.html) as "as all the options there also applies for this component". There is a parameter "**indempotent=true**" that activates usage of an LRUCache:

> Option to use the Idempotent Consumer EIP pattern to let Camel skip
>   already processed files. Will by default use a memory based LRUCache
>   that holds 1000 entries. If noop=true then idempotent will be enabled
>   as well to avoid consuming the same files over and over again.

My complete source definition now looks like this:

```
from("sftp://myhost//path/to/files/?username=user&password=secret&idempotent=true")
```

Comment: You are right, using the idempotent option resolves your problem. Remember to set the file based idempotentrepository option or a custom one, else your will end up with the same problem on restart or when the number of files are more than 1000.

Answer (score 1):

From the camel ftp2 documentation:

> The FTP consumer will by default leave the consumed files untouched on
>   the remote FTP server. You have to configure it explicitly if you want
>   it to delete the files or move them to another location. For example
>   you can use delete=true to delete the files, or use move=.done to move
>   the files into a hidden done sub directory.

To delete the file, change the route to

```
from("sftp://myhost//path/to/files?delete=true")
```

Ensure that the connected user has required permissions.

Comment: Thanks for your comment, but I don't want to delete the source files. My intention is that camel does copy all files from the sftp source and then stops, so I want to achieve a recursive copy like 'cp -r' on Unix but via SFTP. I've found the solution now and I'll post it as answer here.